# VisualForce Page pass Paramters to Component

Tags: lightning

Now I Have a VisualForce Page , And The Third System Will Pass Three Paramters to This Page.

I Want Pass the Paramaters to standard Contact view Page.  But It seems No Possible to Pass Paramaters In lightning Standard Record From VF Page.

However ,Maybe We Can Pass The paramters To other Custom Component From This VisualForce page. And Then we Can try to pass the params to The Record.

I Found A method to createComponent In visualPage . But It's not We Want.

Cause The Component Is In The Page . Not navigation to a Component.

[image]

So  I Have Two Question.

1. Can We Pass Params From VF PAge To Standared Contact Record In Lighting Console?
2. Can We Pass Params From Vf page To a Custom Component?

   It's hard To me  . It Cost us So Many Time.  Any One Know That? Thanks!

Comment: Standard record page is anyways not in our control, why do you want to pass parameters to standard record page?

Comment: @salesforce-sas HI  Bro,  Our RequireMent Is   When A Call Is Coming . We need To Show The  match Contact Record.  And We need To know The CallId.  Do You Have Any Advice? Thank You , My Bro

Answer (score 0):

[lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) will not work when component is loaded in visualforce container. So, below is the other option:

You can use [lightning:recordForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation) to show the record in lightning component instead of navigation.

Below is the sample code:

COMPONENT (POC_AURA):

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="objectApiName" type="String"/>

<lightning:recordForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      objectApiName="{!v.objectApiName}"
                      layoutType="Full"
                      mode="view" />
```

Page:

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightningvf" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:TestCompApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:POC_AURA",
              { 
                  recordId:'00328000008ZUIdAAO',
                  objectApiName: 'Contact'
              },
              "lightningvf",
              function(cmp) {
                console.log("poc was created");
                // do some stuff
              }
          );
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank For Your Answer. Man ,  
Our RequireMent Is When A Call Is Coming . We need To Show The match Contact Record. And We need To know The CallId. 

The Op1 Is Look Like Nice Solution. Unfortunately， The navigation Can't Pass The Call Id To Standard Record.

 The Op2 Is genius ,  I Can CreatedComponent  And Pass The CallId To The Component In Vf JavaScript.  But, We Need To New Case In Contact Record When The Call Is Coming.   ... OHhhhhhh . .. Any Way Thank You .

Comment: Sry for confusion, standard navigation does not work in VF page, modified answer.

Comment: Alright ,Thk You Again